# not able to create stage in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pipeline, stage

```
create or replace stage AWS_OWNER1
url = 's3 url' 
credentials = (aws_key_id = 'aws_key_name' 
               aws_secret_key = 'aws_secret_key')
file_format = CSV;
```

when i run above query i will get error as "SQL compilation error: File format 'CSV' does not exist or not authorized."

please send valied answer to solve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is:

```
file_format = (type = 'CSV')
```

However, as CSV is the default, you can leave this out entirely